# Return contents of string as set of records

Tags: t-sql, ssms, gravity-forms-plugin, ssms-2012

I'm trying to extract the data from a [Gravity Form list control](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/list/).

Essentially the list control allows you to collect multi-column table data on your web form (built on a WordPress website). However, the table and the records the user provides all get put in to a single line of text for the form's record submission.

I've managed to write a custom scalar function to take the raw input text like this:

`a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"1";s:4:"Name";s:10:"Dennis Dish";s:12:"Phone Number";s:12:"01225 123456";}i:1;a:3:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"2";s:4:"Name";s:13:"Sally Spatula";s:12:"Phone Number";s:12:"01225 654321";}i:2;a:3:{s:6:"ItemID";s:1:"3";s:4:"Name";s:10:"Terry Tins";s:12:"Phone Number";s:12:"01225 789456";}}`

...and return it like this (still as a single text string):

```
ItemID: 1
Name: Dennis Dish
Phone Number: 01225 123456

ItemID: 2
Name: Sally Spatula
Phone Number: 01225 654321

ItemID: 3
Name: Terry Tins
Phone Number: 01225 789456
```

That was reasonably straight forward and useful, but I now need to write something that can return the raw string to a set of records instead.

So if, for example, I had a table with the following data:

```
|   ID   |           RawString           |
|--------|-------------------------------|
|   1    | a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:6:"ItemID"... |
```

..instead of returning this as a tidier string, like this:

```
|   ID   |           TidyString          |
|--------|-------------------------------|
|   1    | ItemID: 1 Name: Dennis Dish...|
```

..I'm looking for the method to return something along the lines of:

```
|   ID   | ItemID |     Name      | Phone Number | 
|--------|--------|---------------|--------------|
|   1    |   1    | Dennis Dish   | 01225 123456 |
|   1    |   2    | Sally Spatula | 01225 654321 |
|   1    |   3    | Terry Tins    | 01225 789456 |
```

In my scalar function I was able to identify parts of the raw string formatting that helped to tidy it up:

- `a:n:{...` (at the very start) indicates how many records there are, so `a:3:{...` means
  there are 3 records.
- `i:n;...` indicates the record number, so `i:0;...` means the first
  record.
- `a:n:{...` (within a record) indicates the number of
  column/value pairs in the record, so `a:3:{`means there are 3 pairs
  of columns/values in this record.
- `s:...` indicates the number of characters in following column or value, so `s:2...` indicates the column or value is 2 characters in length.

It may be easier to visualise this by indenting the raw string:

```
a:3:{
        i:0;
            a:3:{
                    s:2:"ItemID";
                    s:1:"1";

                    s:4:"Name";
                    s:10:"Dennis Dish";

                    s:12:"Phone Number";
                    s:12:"01225 123456";
                }
        i:1;
            a:3:{
                    s:2:"ItemID";
                    s:1:"2";

                    s:4:"Name";
                    s:13:"Sally Spatula";

                    s:12:"Phone Number";
                    s:12:"01225 654321";
                }

        i:2;
            a:3:{
                    s:2:"ItemID";
                    s:1:"3";

                    s:4:"Name";
                    s:10:"Terry Tins";

                    s:12:"Phone Number";
                    s:12:"01225 789456";
                }
    }
```

I'm not really sure where to begin in terms of returning the data out of this raw string as a **result set**.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). If you download a copy of the function you could do this:

```
DECLARE @yourstring varchar(1000) =
'a:3:{
    i:0;
        a:3:{
                s:2:"ItemID";
                s:1:"1";

                s:4:"Name";
                s:10:"Dennis Dish";

                s:12:"Phone Number";
                s:12:"01225 123456";
            }
    i:1;
        a:3:{
                s:2:"ItemID";
                s:1:"2";

                s:4:"Name";
                s:13:"Sally Spatula";

                s:12:"Phone Number";
                s:12:"01225 654321";
            }

    i:2;
        a:3:{
                s:2:"ItemID";
                s:1:"3";

                s:4:"Name";
                s:10:"Terry Tins";

                s:12:"Phone Number";
                s:12:"01225 789456";
            }
    }';

WITH 
names(itemID, ps) AS -- extract the names
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position),
    SUBSTRING
    (
      @yourstring, 
      position+7, 
      CHARINDEX(';', @yourstring, position+7)-(position+8)
    )
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@yourstring, 7)
  WHERE token = '"Name";'
),
phoneNbrs(itemID, ps) AS -- extract the phone numbers
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY position),
    SUBSTRING
    (
      @yourstring, 
      position+15, 
      CHARINDEX(';', @yourstring, position+15)-(position+16)
    )
  FROM dbo.NGrams8k(@yourstring, 15)
  WHERE token = '"Phone Number";'

)
SELECT 
 id = 1, 
 n.itemID,
 [Name]         = SUBSTRING(n.ps, CHARINDEX('"', n.ps)+1, 100),
 [Phone Number] = SUBSTRING(p.ps, CHARINDEX('"', p.ps)+1, 30)
FROM names n
JOIN phoneNbrs p ON n.itemID = p.itemID;
```

Results:

```
|   ID   | ItemID |     Name      | Phone Number | 
|--------|--------|---------------|--------------|
|   1    |   1    | Dennis Dish   | 01225 123456 |
|   1    |   2    | Sally Spatula | 01225 654321 |
|   1    |   3    | Terry Tins    | 01225 789456 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your article, Alan - this will take me a while to fully digest and understand how I can get the NGrams8K function to return what I need, but it certainly looks interesting.

Comment: Apologies - didn't initially notice the rest of your answer in that first code block. Thanks very much - this seems to work. Will now tweak it so it can read `@yourstring` from a table column rather than a declared variable.

Comment: Quick question - what is `position` as used above? I've not come across it as a keyword before and can't find any info about it.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you Matt. The position represents a character's position in the string. To better understand what I mean you can run these queries: SELECT * FROM dbo.NGrams8k('abc123', 1);
SELECT * FROM dbo.NGrams8k('abc123', 2);
SELECT * FROM dbo.NGrams8k('abc123', 3);